# Timer and Audio file to play upon click event

Tags: javascript, html, timer

the button plays audio. I'd also like it to also simultaneously start the timer below. As of now the timer starts immediately when the page loads. I'd like for it to only start along with the audio when I press the button. I can't figure out the syntax.

```
 <button class="button1" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()">   
 </button>



 <p> Time ends in  <span id="countdowntimer">10 </span> Seconds</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var timeleft = 10;
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
if(timeleft <= 0)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
},1000);
**strong text**</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `currentTime` and `duration` properties to calculate left time, here is an example:

```js
var sound1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
var countDownTimer = document.getElementById('countdowntimer');

function play() {
  sound1.play();
};

function updateTimer() {
  countDownTimer.textContent = Math.floor(sound1.duration) - Math.floor(sound1.currentTime);
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" src="https://ia902508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3" ontimeupdate="updateTimer()" >
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>

<button class="button1" onclick="play()">Play</button>

<p> Time ends in  <span id="countdowntimer"></span> Seconds</p>
```

Comment: You are welcome, You can accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: It doesn't work for some reason. I see it works when I test it here on the page. but when I copy and paste your code and open it, it does play the audio file and show the text, but not the count down as it does here. Is it necessary for the file to be online, meaning on a server? I have the mp3 file stored locally. could that be the issue?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the file was stored online or locally !!

Comment: Ar there any errors in your javascript console when you play the audio ?

Comment: wait, It does say sound1.mp3 (failed)......but it does play the audio file, maybe something to do with the variable have the same title as the actual audio file perhaps?

Comment: If you want to get the error related to the audio, you need to add error event like this: 
`sound1.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
        alert("Error :" + e);
});`

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. When I paste the error code that you've provided nothing additional happens in the browser. The sound does play and the text does show, but no countdown.

Comment: You can debug the code by using `console.log(sound1.duration)` to see if it works or not